# Unique Pointers in Modern c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have searched throughout the web quite a bit and have found so many different examples of `unique_ptr` implementation in modern c++. I have started to update all of my code starting with `::iterators` into the `auto` and etc. However, with the smart pointers I don't think I understand exactly what I am suppose to be doing.

With a standard pointer I have:

```
 object *temp = new object();
```

Then with the new smart pointer I have:

```
  unquie_ptr<object> temp(new object());
```

Is this not the correct way of implementation? If so, it seems to be more typing / work to make smart pointers when I have a simple cleanup function built at the end of my program?

Comment: Technically it should probably be `std::unique_ptr<object> = std::make_unique<object>();` (i.e., you aren't manually calling `new` or `delete`).

Comment: Even better (or at least shorter and easier), `auto p = std::make_unique<object>();`.

Comment: As @BaummitAugen suggests, you can make the code more succinct by using `auto`.

Comment: I haven't read them in detail but searching for "unique_ptr best practices" in google turned up the following links that sound interesting: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708 and http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/.

Comment: A big reason to use `std::unique_ptr` even though "you could do the cleanup yourelf" is that it clearly conveys the ownership semantics involved (i.e., it's self documenting code) as well as guarantees you don't have to worry about remembering to do any cleanup.

Comment: Note that pointers (smart or not) are usually class members. `object *temp`  as a member leads to an incorrect default copy ctor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use more performant `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`.

However, `make_unique` is not available in C++11, but is in C++14 and above

So

```
std::unique_ptr<object> p = std::make_unique<object>();
```

or

```
auto p = std::make_unique<object>();
```

and similar things go for `shared_ptr`.

In C++11, you can use your expression for `unique_ptr`.

```
unquie_ptr<object> temp(new object());
```

Answer (score 4):

You should probably be using `make_unique` instead of directly calling the constructor to completely remove `new` & `delete` :

```
auto p = std::make_unique<object>();
```

> If so, it seems to be more typing / work to make smart pointers when I
>   have a simple cleanup function built at the end of my program?

As your program becomes bigger and bigger the odds that you will forget to `delete` something you created with `new` will get bigger and bigger which is why a `unique_ptr` is there to help you. And remember, writing less lines of code doesn't mean the code is better.

Answer (score 3):

A smart pointer is an RAII (Resource Allocation is Initialization) container which guarantees that the contained resource is deallocated when the the object goes out of scope. Consider a function that has multiple exit points or the situation where an exception in thrown at some point inside of the function. If cleanup is performed with an explicit call to a dedicated function, that function must be carefully called at every exit point. Furthermore, to insure that resources are not leaked if exception is thrown, that cleanup function must also be called in the exception handler (not to mention that exceptions need to be explicitly handled). With smart pointers, resources will not be leaked if an exception is called since they will be automatically handled when the stack is unwound and the objects fall out of scope.

Smart pointers create a clean abstraction which isolates messy resource management to a low level and insures that resources are not inadvertently leaked.

The initialization syntax overhead is minimal compared to the additional code which would be required to guarantee that resources would be similarly managed with owning raw pointers.

Smart pointers make C++ code safer, smaller, and more maintainable.

Comment: OP didn't inquire about the purpose and advantages of Smart Pointers, but rather how to syntactically implement them.

Answer (score 0):

*("The correct way of implementation?" )*

**Implementation examples:**

```cpp
// UNIQUE PTR
 
auto object = std::make_unique<Object>(); // Object instance

auto i = std::make_unique<int>(5); // int initialized to 5

auto buffer{ std::shared_ptr<char[]>(new char[n]) }; // char array of size n (variable)

// C++11, C++14, C++17: This works too:
auto buffer{ std::make_unique<char[]>(n) }; // char array of size n (variable)
```

```cpp
// SHARED PTR

auto object = std::make_shared<Object>(); // Object instance

auto i = std::make_shared<int>(5); // int initialized to 5

auto buffer{ std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[n]) }; // char array of size n (variable)

// C++11, C++14, C++17: This works too:
auto buffer{ std::make_shared<char[]>(n) }; // char array of size n (variable)
```

You can find more examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).